# Android contacts database: how phone lookup table is be highly optimized?

Tags: android, contacts

When i want use phone_lookup table to query display_name,i find introduce like:

'A table that represents the result of looking up a phone number, for example for caller ID. To perform a lookup you must append the number you want to find to CONTENT_FILTER_URI. This query is highly optimized' 
in android developer.

But i've no idea how did google optimize this query?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup

I made a query.Finally, it's explained as followed:

```
SELECT data1 AS number,
    contacts_view._id AS contact_id,
    contacts_view.photo_uri AS photo_uri,
       contacts_view.send_to_voicemail AS send_to_voicemail,
       data_id AS data_id,
       contacts_view.lookup AS lookup,
       contacts_view.display_name AS display_name,
       contacts_view.last_time_contacted AS last_time_contacted,
       contacts_view.has_phone_number AS has_phone_number,
       contacts_view.in_visible_group AS in_visible_group,
       contacts_view.photo_file_id AS photo_file_id,
       data3 AS label,
       contacts_view.starred AS starred,
       data4 AS normalized_number,
       contacts_view.photo_thumb_uri AS photo_thumb_uri,
       contacts_view.in_default_directory AS in_default_directory,
       contacts_view.photo_id AS photo_id,
       contacts_view.custom_ringtone AS custom_ringtone,
       contacts_view._id AS _id,
       data2 AS type,
       contacts_view.times_contacted AS times_contacted
  FROM raw_contacts
       JOIN
       view_contacts AS contacts_view ON (contacts_view._id = raw_contacts.contact_id),
       (
           SELECT data_id,
                  normalized_number,
                  length(normalized_number) AS len
             FROM phone_lookup
            WHERE (phone_lookup.min_match = '.....') 
       )
       AS lookup,
       data
 WHERE (lookup.data_id = data._id AND 
        data.raw_contact_id = raw_contacts._id AND 
        (lookup.normalized_number = '+......' OR 
         lookup.len <= 11 AND 
         substr('.....', 11 - lookup.len + 1) = lookup.normalized_number OR 
         (lookup.len > 11 AND 
          substr(lookup.normalized_number, lookup.len + 1 - 11) = '.....') ) ) 
 ORDER BY length(lookup.normalized_number) DESC
```

Comment: hello, welcome to SO. they simply map from every phone number in the contacts DB to all the contacts that contain that number (the "key" (phone number) may be formatted in different ways as well), that's it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,I've read source code.I found that 'highly optimized' means database level optimization instead of code level optimization.In more detail, Android create several nonclustered index in the phone_lookup table to improve query speed.
https://blog.csdn.net/skysukai/article/details/84632943